# Improve process of mirroring server database to a client database via JSON?

Tags: ios, json, core-data

I have a ready enterprise (non-AppStore) legacy iOS application for iPad that I need to refactor (it was written by another developer, my predecessor on my current job).

This application fetches its data via JSON from a server having MSSQL database. The database schema has about 30 tables, the most capacious are: Client, City, Agency each having about 10.000 records each and the further growth is expected in the future. After the JSON is received (one JSON request-and-response pair for each table) - it is mapped to the CoreData - the process which also includes glueing together the corresponding CoreData entities (Client, City, Agency and others) with each other i.e. setting the relations beetween these entities on the CoreData layer.

In itself the project's CoreData fetch-part (or read-part) is heavily optimized - it uses, I guess, almost all possible performance and memory tweaks CoreData has, that is why UI layer of application is very fast and responsive, so that I consider its work as completely satisfactory and adequate.

---

**The problem** is the process of preparation of CoreData layer, i.e. the server-to-client synchronization process: it takes too much time. Consider 30 network requests resulting in 30 JSON packs ("pack" I mean "one table - one JSON"), which are then mapped to 30 CoreData entities, which are then glued together (the appropriate CoreData relations are set beetween them). When I first saw how all this is done in this project (too slow), the first idea to come into my head was:

"For the first time a complete synchronization is performed (app's first launch time) - perform a fetch of **the whole database** data in, say, one archived file (something like database dump) and then somehow import it as a whole to a Core Data land".

But then I realized that, even if such transmission of such one-file dump was possible, CoreData would still require me to perform a gluing of the corresponding CoreData entities to set the appropriate relations beetween them so that it is hard to imagine that I could benefit in performance if I would rely on this scheme.

Also, my colleague suggested me to consider SQLite as a complete alternative to Core Data, but unfortunately I don't have an experience of using it, that's why I am completely blind to foresee all the consequences of such serious design decision (even having the synchronization process very slow, my app *does work*, especially its UI performance is very good now). The only thing I can imagine about SQLite that in contrast to Core Data it will not push me to glue some additional relations on a client side, because SQLite has its good old foreign key system, doesn't it?

---

And so here are the questions (Respondents, please do not mix these points when you answer - there is too much confusion I have about all of them):

1. Does anybody have such experience of taking "first-time large import of the whole database" approach in a way I have described above? I would be very thankful to know about any solutions should they exploit JSON<->CoreData pair or not.
2. Does Core Data has some global import mechanism which can allow mass-creation of corresponding 30-tables-schema (possibly using some specific source other than "30 packs of JSON" described above) without a need of setting up corresponding relations for 30 entities?
3. Are there any possibilities to speed up the synchronization process if *2)* is impossible? Here I mean the improvements of current JSON<->CoreData scheme my app uses.
4. Migration to SQLite: should I consider such migration? What I will benefit from it? How the whole process of *replication->transmission->client preparations* could look like then?
5. Other alternatives to CoreData and SQLite - what could they be or look like?
6. Any other thoughts or visions you may have about the situation I've described?

---

**UPDATE 1**

Though the answer written by Mundi is good (one large JSON, "No" for using SQLite), I am still interested if there are any other insights into the the problem I've described.

---

**UPDATE 2**

I did try to use my russian english the best way I could to describe my situation in a hope for my question could become pretty clear to everyone who will read it. By this second update I will try to provide it with some more guides to make my question even more clear.

Please, consider two dichotomies:

1. What can/should I use as a data layer on iOS client - CoreData vs SQLite?
2. What can/should I use as a transport layer - JSON (single-JSON-at-once as suggested in the answer, even zipped maybe) or some DB-itself-dumps (if it is even possible, of course - notice I am also asking this in my question).

I think it is pretty obvious the "sector" which is formed by intersection of these two dichotomies, choosing CoreData from the first one and JSON from the second is the most wide-spread default in iOS development world and also it is used by my app from this question.

Having that said, I claim that I would be thankful to see any answers regarding CoreData-JSON pair as well as the answers considering using any other "sectors" (what about opting SQLite and some kind of its dumps approach, why not?)

Also, important to note, that I don't want to just drop the current option for some other alternatives, I just want to get the solution working fast on both synchronization and UI phases of its usage. So answers about improving current scheme as well as answers suggesting the other schemes are welcome!

Now, please see the following update #3 which provides more details for my current CoreData-JSON situation:

---

**UPDATE 3**

As I have said, currently my app receives 30 packs of JSON - one pack for the whole table. Let's take capacious tables for example: Client, Agency, City.

It is Core Data, so if a `client` record has non-empty `agency_id` field, I need to create new Core Data entity of class `Agency (NSManagedObject subclass)` and fill it with this record's JSON data, that's why I need to already have corresponding Core Data entity for this agency of class `Agency (NSManagedObject's subclass)`, and finally I need to do something like `client.agency = agency;` and then call `[currentManagedObjectContext save:&error]`. Having it done this way, later I can then ask this client to be fetched and ask its `.agency` property to find corresponding entity. I hope I am completely sane when I do it this way.

Now imagine this pattern applied to the following situation:

I have just received the following 3 separate JSON packs: 10000 clients and 4000 cities and 6000 agencies (client has one city, city has many clients; client has agency, agency has many clients, agency has one city, city has many agencies).

Now I want to setup the following relations on Core Data level: I want my client entity `client` to be connected to a corresponding city and corresponding agency.

The current implementation of this in the project does very ugly thing:

1. Since dependency order is the following: City -> Agency -> Client i.e. the City needs to be baked first, the application begins creating entities for City and persists them to Core Data.
2. Then it deals with the JSON of agencies: it iterates through every JSON record - for every agency, it creates a new entity `agency` and by its `city_id`, it fetches corresponding entity `city` and connects it using the `agency.city = city`. After the iteration through the whole agencies JSON array is done, current managed object context is saved (actually the -[managedObjectContext save:] is done several times, each after 500 records processed). At this step it is obvious that fetching one of 4000 cities for every client for every of 6000 agencies has a huge performance impact on the whole synchronization process.
3. Then, finally it deals with the JSON of clients: like in previous 2 stage, it iterates through the whole 10000-elements JSON array and one by one performs the fetch of corresponding agencies and ZOMG cities, and this impacts the overall performance in the same manner like previous stage 2 does.

It is all very BAD.

The only performance optimization I can see here, is that the first stage could leave a large dictionary with cities ids (I mean NSNumber's of real ids) and faulted City entities as values) so it would be possible to prevent ugly **find** process of the following stage 2 and then do the same on the stage 3 using the analogous caching trick, but the problem is that there are much more relations beetween all the 30 tables that just-described [ Client-City, Client-Agency, Agency-City ] so the final procedure involving a caching of all the entities will the most probably hit the resources iPad device reserves for my app.

---

**UPDATE 4**

Message for future respondents: I've tried my best to make this answer well-detailed and well-formed and I really expect you to answer with **verbose** answers. It would be great if your answer would really address the complexity of problem discussed here and complement my efforts I've made to make my question clear and general as much as possible. Thanks.

**UPDATE 5**

Related topics: [Core Data on client (iOS) to cache data from a server Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878586/core-data-on-client-ios-to-cache-data-from-a-server-strategy), [Trying to make a POST request with RestKit and map the response to Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962109/trying-to-make-a-post-request-with-restkit-and-map-the-response-to-core-data/13965675#13965675).

**UPDATE 6**

Even after it is no more possible to open new bounties and there is accepted answer, I still would be glad to see any other answers containing additional information about the problem this topic addresses. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, your question is mainly about how to set up the relationships efficiently? How is your code doing that now? There are optimizations, but which ones are you already using?

Comment: Please notice that I'am talking about the optimizations of fetch-part - "fetch-part (or read-part) is heavily optimized" - actually it means that it is just a regular CoreData fetching - as described in docs with all the fetching tweaks described here (pre-fetching, fetching only the properties which are needed and so on), i.e. nothing magical, but I am calling it "heavily" because if you have ever seen the initial state in which I got this my legacy project, you would wonder how CoreData could be misused so much!..

Comment: Having that said, I will try to update my question to provide it with more guides about what I am trying to achieve by this question. I hope it will also address @Alex needs. Give me a minute)

Comment: Please see the update #3 I've just written. I hope I've described the problem of my project pretty well.

Comment: Do you have gzip/deflate compression active on your server?

Comment: I've just asked server guys about that - the answer is "no".

Comment: This is tricky, but what about creating the Core Data SQLite Database server side (where there are more computing resources) and transfer it to the iOS devices (zipped)? It would need a bit of reverse engineering to understand how data are mapped inside the sqlite database, but it should't be so difficult

Comment: Re: Update 4: You already had this after Mundi and I answered, what else are you looking for? If you don't like our answers, why not give some clue what else you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've decided to write my own answer summarizing the techniques and advices I found useful for my situation. Thanks to all folks who posted their answers.

---

**I. Transport**

1. "One JSON". This is the idea that I want to give a try. Thanks **@mundi**.
2. The idea of archiving JSON before sending it to a client, be it a one JSON pack or a 30 separate 'one table - one pack'.

---

**II. Setting up Core Data relations**

I will describe a process of importing JSON->CoreData import using imaginary large import operation as if it was performed in one method (I am not sure will it be so or not - maybe I split it into a logical chunks).

Let's imagine that in my imaginary app there are 15 capacious tables, where "capacious" means "cannot be held in memory at once, should be imported using batches" and 15 non-capacious tables each having <500 records, for example:

Capacious:

- cities (15k+)
- clients (30k+)
- users (15k+)
- events (5k+)
- actions (2k+)
  ...

Small:

- client_types  (20-)
- visit_types (10-)
- positions (10-)
  ...

Let's imagine, that I already have JSON packs downloaded and parsed into composite NSArray/NSDictionary variables: I have citiesJSON, clientsJSON, usersJSON, ...

**1. Work with small tables first**

My pseudo-method starts with import of tiny tables first. Let's take client_types table: I iterate through `clientTypesJSON` and create `ClientType` objects (NSManagedObject's subclasses). More than that I collect resulting objects in a dictionary with these objects as its values and "ids" (foreign keys) of these objects as keys.

Here is the pseudocode:

```
NSMutableDictionary *clientTypesIdsAndClientTypes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (NSDictionary *clientTypeJSON in clientsJSON) {
    ClientType *clientType = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ClientType" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    // fill the properties of clientType from clientTypeJSON

    // Write prepared clientType to a cache
    [clientTypesIdsAndClientTypes setValue:clientType forKey:clientType.id];
}

// Persist all clientTypes to a store.
NSArray *clientTypes = [clientTypesIdsAndClientTypes allValues];
[managedObjectContext obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:clientTypes error:...];

// Un-fault (unload from RAM) all the records in the cache - because we don't need them in memory anymore.
for (ClientType *clientType in clientTypes) {
    [managedObjectContext refreshObject:clientType mergeChanges:NO];
}
```

The result is that we have a bunch of dictionaries of small tables, each having corresponding set of objects and their ids. We will use them later without a refetching because they are small and their values (NSManagedObjects) are now faults.

**2. Use the cache dictionary of objects from small tables obtained during step 1 to set up relationships with them**

Let's consider complex table `clients`: we have `clientsJSON` and we need to set up a `clientType` relation for each client record, it is easy because we do have a cache with `clientTypes` and their ids:

```
for (NSDictionary *clientJSON in clientsJSON) {
    Client *client = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Client" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    // Setting up SQLite field 
    client.client_type_id = clientJSON[@"client_type_id"];

    // Setting up Core Data relationship beetween client and clientType
    client.clientType = clientTypesIdsAndClientTypes[client.client_type_id];
}

// Save and persist
```

**3. Dealing with large tables - batches**

Let's consider a large `clientsJSON` having 30k+ clients in it. We do not iterate through the whole `clientsJSON` but split it into a chunks of appropriate size (500 records), so that `[managedObjectContext save:...]` is called every 500 records. Also it is important to wrap operation with each 500-records batch into an `@autoreleasepool block` - see [Reducing memory overhead in Core Data Performance guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003468-SW4)

Be careful - the step 4 describes the operation applied to a batch of 500 records not to a whole `clientsJSON`!

**4. Dealing with large tables - setting up relationships with large tables**

Consider the following method, we will use in a moment:

```
@implementation NSManagedObject (Extensions)
+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryOfExistingObjectsByIds:(NSArray *)objectIds inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    NSDictionary *dictionaryOfObjects;

    NSArray *sortedObjectIds = [objectIds sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass(self)];

    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(id IN %@)", sortedObjectIds];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey: @"id" ascending:YES]];

    fetchRequest.includesPropertyValues = NO;
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = YES;

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *fetchResult = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    dictionaryOfObjects = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:fetchResult forKeys:sortedObjectIds];

    return dictionaryOfObjects;
}
@end
```

Let's consider `clientsJSON` pack containing a batch (500) of `Client` records we need to save. Also we need to set up a relationship beetween these clients and their agencies (`Agency`, foreign key is `agency_id`).

```
NSMutableArray *agenciesIds = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *clients = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSDictionary *clientJSON in clientsJSON) {
    Client *client = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Client" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    // fill client fields...

    // Also collect agencies ids
    if ([agenciesIds containsObject:client.agency_id] == NO) {
        [agenciesIds addObject:client.agency_id];
    }        

    [clients addObject:client];
}

NSDictionary *agenciesIdsAndAgenciesObjects = [Agency dictionaryOfExistingObjectsByIds:agenciesIds];

// Setting up Core Data relationship beetween Client and Agency
for (Client *client in clients) {
    client.agency = agenciesIdsAndAgenciesObjects[client.agency_id];
}

// Persist all Clients to a store.
[managedObjectContext obtainPermanentIDsForObjects:clients error:...];

// Un-fault all the records in the cache - because we don't need them in memory anymore.
for (Client *client in clients) {
    [managedObjectContext refreshObject:client mergeChanges:NO];
}
```

Most of what I use here is described in these Apple guides: [Core Data performance](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003468-SW4), [Efficiently importing data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003174-SW4). So the summary for steps 1-4 is the following:

1. Turn objects into faults when they are persisted and so their property values become unnecessary as import operation goes futher.
2. Construct dictionaries with objects as values and their `ids` as keys, so these dictionaries can serve as lookup tables when constructing a relationships beetween these objects and other objects.
3. Use @autoreleasepool when iterating through a large number of records.
4. Use a method similar to `dictionaryOfExistingObjectsByIds` or to a method that Tom references in his answer, from [Efficiently importing data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003174-SW4) - a method that has SQL `IN` predicate behind it to significantly reduce a number of fetches. Read Tom's answer and referenced Apple's corresponding guide to better understand this technique.

---

**Good reading on this topic**

[objc.io issue #4: Importing Large Data Sets](http://www.objc.io/issue-4/importing-large-data-sets-into-core-data.html)

Answer (score 10):

I have experience in a very similar project. The Core Data insertions take some time, so we condition the user that this will take a while, but only *the first time*. The best performance tweak was of course to get the batch size right between saves, but I am sure you are aware of that.

One performance suggestion: I have tried a few things and found that creating many download threads can be a hit on performance, I suppose because for each request there is some latency from the server etc.

Instead, I discovered that downloading all the JSON **in one go** was much faster. I do not know how much data you have, but I tested with > 100.000 records and a 40MB+ JSON string this works really fast, so the bottleneck is just the Core Data insertions. With an `@autorelease` pool this even performed acceptably on a first generation iPad.

Stay away from the SQLite API - it will take you more than a man year (provided high productivity) to replicate the performance optimizations you get out of the box with Core Data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've got what you had said!

Comment: @Alex Let me reiterate: I found that JSON file size is *not* the bottleneck.

Comment: @Mundi, sorry, I was tired and wrote confusing comment. Are we talking about amount of files? One JSON vs many JSON's?

Comment: @Alex Both amount and size. Best is *one* file, the smaller the better. But the actual size is not so critical - that's my point.

Comment: 40MB+ JSON file fetched from a server on an iOS device... Two thing  springs to mind namely Network connectivity issue and download speeds. I certainly hope that that a big file will downloaded in chunks.

Answer (score 6):

First off, you're doing a lot of work, and it will take some time no matter how you slice it, but there are ways to improve things.

I'd recommend doing your fetches in batches, with a batch size matching your batch size for processing new objects. For example, when creating new `Agency` records, do something like:

1. Make sure the current `Agency` batch is sorted by `city_id`. (I'll explain why later).
2. Get the `City` ID for each `Agency` in the batch. Depending on how your JSON is structured, this is probably a one-liner like this (since `valueForKey` works on arrays):

   ```
   NSArray *cityIDs = [myAgencyBatch valueForKey:@"city_id"];
   ```
3. Get all the `City` instances for the current pass in one fetch by using the IDs you found in the previous step. Sort the results by `city_id`. Something like:

   ```
   NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"City"];
   NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"city_id in %@", cityIDs];
   [request setPredicate:predicate];
   [request setSortDescriptors:@[ [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"city_id" ascending:YES] ]];
   NSArray *cities = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
   ```

**Now**, you have one array of `Agency` and another one of `City`, both sorted by `city_id`. Match them up to set up the relationships (check `city_id` in case things don't match). Save changes, and go on to the next batch.

This will dramatically reduce the number of fetches you need to do, which should speed things up. For more on this technique, see [Implementing Find-or-Create Efficiently](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003174-SW4) in Apple's docs.

Another thing that may help is to "warm up" Core Data's internal cache with the objects you need before you start fetching them. This will save time later on because getting property values won't require a trip to the data store. For this you'd do something like:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"City"];
// no predicate, get everything
[request setResultType:NSManagedObjectIDResultType];
NSArray *notUsed = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
```

..and then just forget about the results. This is superficially useless but will alter the internal Core Data state for faster access to `City` instances later on.

Now as for your other questions,

- Using SQLite directly instead of Core Data might not be a terrible choice for your situation. The benefit would be that you'd have no need to set up the relationships, since you could use use fields like `city_id` as foreign keys. So, fast importing. The downside, of course, is that you'll have to do your own work converting your model objects to/from SQL records, and probably rewrite quite a lot of existing code that assumes Core Data (e.g. every time you follow a relationship you now need to look up records by that foreign key). This change might fix your import performance issues, but the side effects could be significant.
- JSON is generally a very good format if you're transmitting data as text. ***If*** you could prepare a Core Data store on the server, and ***if*** you would use that file as-is instead of trying to merge it into an existing data store, then that would almost certainly speed things up. Your import process would run once on the server and then never again. But those are big "if"s, especially the second one. If you get to where you need to merge a new server data store with existing data, you're right back to where you are now.

Comment: I am aware of this "Implementing Find-or-Create Efficiently" and actually this is exactly what I've described in UPDATE 3 as a next optimization I was going to make - mine variant with dictionary is just a generalized version of what is described in this section of Core Data Programming Guide - instead of having two sorted arrays - array of ids and array of their corresponding objects - I just have a dictionary. Mine variant being more universal gives me a possibility to glue my client with more than one entity but with two or more when I iterate through a current clients batch.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, especially for the "warm up" trick - I didn't know about that. Is it ok to fetch the whole bunch (fx 10000) of entities? (I do know that they are faulted, but anyway...)

Comment: Should be OK, they're faults and Core Data should manage the cache.

Comment: One more question while I have you online) - does it really mean that I will finally find myself having a large complex method involving just the processing of Client and all its dependencies i.e. gluing all these Core Data entities Client, Agency, ... with each other - I mean "one large method for every entity with 2> dependencies"??? I know this exclamation sounds rhetorically but I imagine this method containing a final implementation of all this glueing stuff to be really large in size. Is it so in real projects having complex database structures and large capacities?! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, yeah, maybe. It's possible to write generic import code, but if you do so, you're not making use of any of your knowledge of the data to optimize the process. So it works, but is slower and maybe uses a lot of memory. When you start making use of what you know about your data, you write more domain specific code, but you get better results. You might be able to make it semi-generic by using a lookup table of entity and key names to drive the process, but that can easily end up being even harder to maintain.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You've just confirmed my suspicions about writing generic code before a moment when code involving all the possible optimizations is written first (maybe it will have a large number of lines and be not enough generic - but at least then maybe it will be a good point to start any abstractions&generalizations from).

Answer (score 5):

Do you have control of the server? I ask, because it sounds like you do from the following paragraph:

> "For the first time a complete synchronization is performed (app's first launch time) - perform the fetch of the whole database data in, say, one archived file (something like database dump) and then somehow import it as a whole to the CoreData land".

If sending a dump is possible, why not send the Core Data file itself? Core Data (by default) is backed by a SQLite database -- why not generate that database on the server, zip it and send it across the wire?

This would mean you could eliminate all the JSON parsing, network requests etc and replace it with a simple file download and archive extraction. We did this on a project and it improved performance immeasurably.

Comment: [re-edited comment] Thanks for the answer. Sending database dump from a server is one of the options I am considering but right now I am not sure how many steps I can ask server guys to walk away from the current working scheme - our communication is not so easy (they are kind of being from "different department") Besides sending a zipped db dump I also consider a transmission of a zip-archive of a whole JSON file - it would look very similar to yours variant with zipping the Core Data itself with the additional JSON->CoreData glueing work on my shoulders.

Comment: By the way, what do you mean by "Core Data file itself" - is this an SQLite dump or what? Could you update your answer with more details on that?

Comment: This is a nice idea - but the problem is to create a Core Data managed SQLite database on the server. That process needs to run automatically. A solution to this problem would deserve its own Question on SO. ;)

Answer (score 4):

1. For each row in your table there must be a **timestamp** column. If there isn't one, you should add it.
2. First time and each time you fetch database dump you store last update date and time.
3. On every next time you instruct the database to return only those records that were changed or updated since the previous download operation. There also should be a "deleted" flag for you to remove vanished records.
4. Then you only need to [update certain matching records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571786/how-to-update-existing-object-in-core-data) saving time on all fronts.

To speed up the first time sync you can also ship a seed database with the app, so that it could be imported immediately without any network operations.

1. Download the JSON files by hand.
2. [Put them into your project.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418680/subdirectories-within-an-ios-application)
3. Somewhere in the project configuration or header files take a note of download date and time.
4. On the first run, locate and load said files, then proceed like you're updating them.
5. If in doubt, [refer to the manual.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html)

Example:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cities" 
                                            ofType:@"json"];
NSData *citiesData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
// I assume that you're loading an array
NSArray *citiesSeed = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:citiesData 
                       options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My app already does what you describe. The scope of my question is really about the _first_ time a sync process is performed.

Comment: @Stanislaw I must say that your question is little too much detailed. See my updated answer. Do you really want me to go into such details?

Comment: Sorry, @sanmai, I made a stupid mistake and commented the wrong answer.

Comment: Now the real comment to your "see addition to the answer": the "seed" approach is not an option in my case because on server there are large amounts of data that constantly change. I don't like the idea of pre-packaging seed database because pre-packaged information will become too much outdated before the new releases will appear.

Comment: I've just deleted the wrong comment. Sorry again. It was not addressed to you.

Comment: Don't know about other databases, but cities database isn't expected to change frequently. I think you may use this approach at least for some databases.

Answer (score 4):

Here you have my recommendations:

- Use [magicalrecord](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord). It's a CoreData wrapper that saves you a lot of boilerplate code, plus it comes with very interesting features.
- Download all the JSON in one request, as others suggested. If you can embed the first JSON document into the app, you can save the download time and start populating the database right when you open the app for the first time. Also, with magicalrecord is quite easy to perform this save operation in a separate thread and then sync all contexts automatically. This can improve the responsiveness of your app.
- It seems that you should refactor that *ugly method* once you have solved the first import issue. Again, I would suggest to use magicalrecord to easily create those entities.

Answer (score 3):

We've recently moved a fairly large project from Core Data to SQLite, and one of the main reasons was bulk insert performance. There were quite a few features we lost in the transition, and I would not advise you to make the switch if you can avoid it. After the transition to SQLite, we actually had performance issues in areas other than bulk inserts which Core Data was transparently handling for us, and even though we fixed those new issues, it took some amount of time getting back up and running. Although we've spent some time and effort in transitioning from Core Data to SQLite, I can't say that there are any regrets.

With that cleared up, I'd suggest you get some baseline measurements before you go about fixing the  bulk insert performance.

1. Measure how long it takes to insert those records in the current state.
2. Skip setting up the relationships between those objects altogether, and then measure the insert performance.
3. Create a simple SQLite database, and measure the insert performance with that. This should give you a very good baseline estimate of how long it takes to perform the actual SQL inserts and will also give you a good idea of the Core Data overhead.

A few things you can try off the bat to speed up inserts:

1. Ensure that there are no active fetched results controllers when you are performing the bulk inserts.  By active, I mean fetched result controllers that have a non-nil delegate. In my experience, Core Data's change tracking was the single most expensive operation when trying to do bulk insertions.
2. Perform all changes in a single context, and stop merging changes from different contexts until this bulk inserts are done.

To get more insight into what's really going on under the hood, enable [Core Data SQL debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428630/xcode4-and-core-data-how-to-enable-sql-debugging) and see the SQL queries that are being executed. Ideally, you'd want to see a lot of INSERTs, and a few UPDATEs. But if you come across too many SELECTs, and/or UPDATEs, then that's a sign that you are doing too much reading, or updating of objects.

Use the Core-Data profiler instrument to get a better high-level overview of what's going on with Core Data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will use your suggestions as the guides for my forecoming refactoring work!